# How to find the values in the other dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two df, and want use df['Names'] to map to reference_table, and put them together.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Names': ['John, Mary, Bob'],
                   'Ages': ['25, 32, 40']})

reference_table = pd.DataFrame({'Names': ['John', 'Mary', 'Bob'],
                                'Cities': ['New York', 'London', 'Paris'],
                                'Countries': ['USA', 'UK', 'France'],
                                'Famous_Landmarks': ['Statue of Liberty', 'Big Ben', 'Eiffel Tower']})

split_df = pd.DataFrame(df.Names.str.split(',', expand=True).stack().str.strip(), columns=['Names'])
split_df['Ages'] = df.Ages.str.split(',').tolist()[0]

merged_df = pd.merge(split_df, reference_table, on='Names')


grouped_df = merged_df.groupby('Ages').agg({'Cities': lambda x: ', '.join(x.unique()),
                                            'Countries': lambda x: ', '.join(x.unique()),
                                            'Famous_Landmarks': lambda x: ','.join(x.unique())}).reset_index()

final_df = pd.merge(df, grouped_df, on='Ages')


final_df.rename(columns={'Cities': 'Cities_List', 'Countries': 'Countries_List', 'Famous_Landmarks': 'Famous_Landmarks_List'}, inplace=True)

print(final_df)
```

**here are two data frames and what the result is like below**

```
             Names         Ages           Cities_List Countries_List   Famous_Landmarks_List
0  John, Mary, Bob  25, 32, 40  New York, London, Paris  USA, UK, France  Statue of Liberty, Big Ben, Eiffel Tower
```

Comment: So the last output is your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

So I understand, you want to merge the two dataframes on `df['name']`? It would be helpful if you posted the output you'd like to see.

Here is what I understand you want:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Names': ['John', 'Mary', 'Bob'], 'Ages': [25, 32, 40]})

reference_table = pd.DataFrame({'Names': ['John', 'Mary', 'Bob'],
                                'Cities': ['New York', 'London', 'Paris'],
                                'Countries': ['USA', 'UK', 'France'],
                                'Famous_Landmarks': ['Statue of Liberty', 'Big Ben', 'Eiffel Tower']})
df.merge(reference_table, on="Names")
```

[image]

Comment: yes, but the name in df can't merge with reference_table name

Comment: your lists in your dataframe contain a single string `['John, Mary, Bob']` instead of individual elements `["John", "Mary", "Bob"]`. Once you split those apart, you'll be able to merge them together easily. Same with `df['ages']`